# MySQL Cursor with Distinct returning too many rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following procedure:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_default_apps()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_app_nm VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_app_typ VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_employer_id VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE existing_apps cursor for select distinct APP_NM, EMPLOYER_ID, APP_TYP from USER_APP;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    open existing_apps;
    create_default_apps: LOOP
        fetch existing_apps into v_app_nm, v_employer_id, v_app_typ;
        insert into APP(ID, APP_NM, EXTERNAL_ID, APP_TYP, LAST_CHANGED_DT, LAST_CHANGED_BY, CREATED_DT, CREATED_BY) values(UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')), v_app_nm, v_employer_id, v_app_typ, sysdate(), 'testuser', sysdate(), 'testuser');
    end loop create_default_apps;
    close existing_apps;
END$$
```

There are only 85 rows in the USER_APP table, but for some reason when I run this procedure, it runs until I manually terminating it, as if the "select distinct" is returning much, much more than 85 rows. Am I just missing something super obvious here?

Comment: Within the iteration of the cursor loop, you must handle the variable `done` to exit the loop. `IF \`done\` THEN LEAVE  \`create_default_apps\` END IF;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
...
open existing_apps;

create_default_apps: LOOP
    fetch existing_apps into v_app_nm, v_employer_id, v_app_typ;
    IF `done` THEN
        close existing_apps;
        LEAVE `create_default_apps`;    
    END IF;
    insert into APP(ID, APP_NM, EXTERNAL_ID, APP_TYP, LAST_CHANGED_DT, LAST_CHANGED_BY, CREATED_DT, CREATED_BY)
    values (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')), v_app_nm, v_employer_id, v_app_typ, sysdate(), 'testuser', sysdate(), 'testuser');
end loop create_default_apps;

-- close existing_apps;
...
```

Comment: Oh crap, I don't know how I missed that!